# How to differentiate with respect to component of a vector?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, vectors

Let $\vec{\alpha}=\frac{m(\vec{x})}{x^2}\vec{x}$

where $\vec{x}=(x_1,\,x_2)$.

In a [book](http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~jmerten/misc/meneghetti_lensing.pdf) I read in Eq.(3.24), it was given that

$$
\frac{\partial \alpha_1}{\partial x_1}=\frac{d m}{d x}\frac{x_1^2}{x^3}+m\frac{x^2_2-x_1^2}{x^4}
$$

Is it possible to show why this is so?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure it's $m(\vec{x})$ and not $m(x)$ in the expression for $\vec{\alpha}$ at the top? I suspect it's $m(x)$ where $x = |\vec{x}|$ is the magnitude of $\vec{x}$.

Comment: What work have you done so far and where are you stuck? The $x^2$ in the denominator on the RHS of the equation defining $\vec{\alpha}$ is meant to be interpreted as $x_1^2 + x_2^2$? Is $\frac{d m}{dx}$ meant to be interpreted as $\frac{\partial m}{\partial x_1}$?

Comment: Looking at the book you referred to, I see that the question refers to eq (3.23) and the expressions following it. I have to say that the book's notation is very sloppy because in eq (3.27) you see $m(x)$ rather than $m(\vec{x})$. Again, I'm convinced it's all $m(x)$, where $x = |\vec{x}|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it should really be

$$\vec{\alpha} = \frac{m(x)}{x^2}\,\vec{x}$$

(see my comments below the question), where $x = |\vec{x}| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$, then

$$\alpha_1 = \frac{m(x)}{x^2}\,x_1$$
and
$$\alpha_2 = \frac{m(x)}{x^2}\,x_2$$

So,

$$
\frac{\partial\alpha_1}{\partial x_1} =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\big(\frac{m(x)}{x^2}\,x_1\big) =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\big(\frac{m(x)}{x^2}\big)\,x_1 +
\frac{m(x)}{x^2}
$$

Now,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x_1} = 2x\,\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_1} = 2x_1$$

so

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_1} = \frac{x_1}{x}$$

(the above is a nice trick to avoid dealing with the square-root in $|\vec{x}|$) and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} = \frac{x_1}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

Therefore,

$$
\frac{\partial\alpha_1}{\partial x_1} =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\big(\frac{m(x)}{x^2}\big)\,x_1 +
\frac{m(x)}{x^2} =
\frac{x_1^2}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{m(x)}{x^2}\big) +
\frac{m(x)}{x^2}
$$

But

$$\frac{d}{dx}\big(\frac{m(x)}{x^2}\big) = \frac{m'(x)}{x^2} - \frac{2m(x)}{x^3}$$

and

$$
\frac{\partial\alpha_1}{\partial x_1} =
\frac{x_1^2}{x}\,\big(\frac{m'(x)}{x^2} - \frac{2m(x)}{x^3}\big) +
\frac{m(x)}{x^2}
$$

Simplifying, you find

$$
\frac{\partial\alpha_1}{\partial x_1} =
\frac{x_1^2}{x^3}\,m'(x) + \frac{x^2 - 2x_1^2}{x^4}\,m(x) =
\frac{x_1^2}{x^3}\,m'(x) + \frac{x_2^2 - x_1^2}{x^4}\,m(x)
$$